# Generate incremental unique IDs for users on registration

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I have a website wherein I need to users to register themselves by adding their details and submitting. On submitting each user should be allocated incremental unique ids. To test this I had 15 users enter necessary details on the site and then click on register simultaneously, however two set of users got the same ids allocated to them. This is not a problem when all register at different times, then the allocation of ids is unique.

How do I ensure each user gets unique ids even when they register simultaneously.

Comment: Why incremental? Why does that matter? From a security standpoint, it is unsecure since it is easily and obviously guess-able.

Comment: "They got same ids" - why is there no primary key or unique constraint to prevent this logic error?

Answer (score 1):

The "easiest" way to give each user a unique ID would be to either use an [`IDENTITY` column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-ver15) on your user table (if you want the ID to be allocated when the record is successfully written to it), or a [`SEQUENCE` object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) if you want to get a unique ID *before* creating the user account in the database.

```
create table MyUserTable (
UserID int identity(1,1) NOT NULL constraint PK_MyUserTable PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
,UserName nvarchar(50)
,Email nvarchar(100);

insert into MyUserTable output inserted.UserId values ('MyUserName', 'me@example.com');
```

Will write the record to the table and return the ID that was created.

If you want to fetch an ID before writing to the table:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE UserIds as int start with 1 increment by 1;

create table MyUserTable (
UserID int NOT NULL constraint PK_MyUserTable PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
,UserName nvarchar(50)
,Email nvarchar(100);

select next value for UserIds

-- Do whatever you need to do in the application

insert into MyUserTable (UserId,UserName,Email) values (UserIdYouGotEarlier, 'MyUserName','me@example.com');
```

Understand that with both approaches, you are not guaranteed to have sequential IDs. In the case of a transaction rollback, these will both still auto-increment and those values will be "lost." But you shouldn't be depending upon them being sequential in the first place.

You'll probably want a unique constraint on those username fields too.